# MySql error authentication with old passward

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, asp-classic, mysql-workbench

I'm working on a shared host where I don't have much control over the SQL setup, so I'm quite limited here. I got the right connection parameters working in the MySQL workbench and the connection works through that (queries can be executed), however, when I create the connection string in C#, I cannot connect. This is my error:

Authentication with old password no longer supported, use 4.1 style passwords.

Is there any solution to this that I can fix client side? I cannot change any settings in the SQL file (root password settings, etc), but if it can be done in the MySQL workbench, I can't see why I can't do it in C#.

Comment: there is a question similar to yours at:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13706463/authentication-method-mysql-old-password-not-supported

Are your program versions similar to those mentioned in the question there?

Comment: @ThomasE. my question is that when i try to connect from C# to mysql workbench than a dialog box appear and ask about user name ,host n password .. but i dnt nw that on installation time i give any password

Answer (score 0):

Check the solutions mentioned in following links

```
SET SESSION old_passwords=0;
SET PASSWORD FOR my_user=PASSWORD('my_password');
```

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/3116f713-6665-4adc-89a1-4d267cca2e7f/authentication-with-old-password-no-longer-supported-use-41-style-passwords?forum=sqldataaccess

[Authentication with old password no longer supported, use 4.1 style passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15772479/authentication-with-old-password-no-longer-supported-use-4-1-style-passwords)

Comment: @britnan where to apply this query  plz tell me

Comment: In your query window change the 'my_user' to your mysql user name . and my_password to ur my sql password