# NotSupportedError: (NotSupportedError) Authentication plugin 'mysql_old_password' is not supported

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, pandas, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to connect to a remote MySQL server, specifically using Python 2.7/pandas/sqlalchemy.

I installed installed mysql-connector-python, then initiated iPython in my terminal, then tried:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Series, DataFrame
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqlconnector://scott:tiger@localhost:3306/foo')
test_q = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT COUNT(users.id) FROM users', engine)
```

Of course, the create_engine() here is not the actual connection, it's just an example.

I'm getting the error:

```
NotSupportedError: (NotSupportedError) Authentication plugin 'mysql_old_password' is not supported None None
```

I'm having a difficult time understanding this error and how to fix it. I think there might be something about the fact that I'm just sending the password as a string, whereas it may require [some type encryption](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/old-client.html).

So based on [this documentation](http://www.pythoncentral.io/hashing-strings-with-python/), I tried:

```
import hashlib
hash_object = hashlib.sha256(b'tiger')
engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqlconnector://scott:' + hash_object + '@localhost/foo')
```

Which raised the error:

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and '_hashlib.HASH' objects
```

So now I think I need to use [the engine creation API](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/engines.html#custom-dbapi-connect-arguments) to create the connection object. The [custom dbapi connection](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/engines.html#custom-dbapi-connect-arguments) could be another possibility, but I'm still at a loss though following the directions for either. Any ideas?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13706463/authentication-method-mysql-old-password-not-supported

Comment: I'm not the admin for the DB and I don't think they're going to change anything to 'old_passwords=1'; from the link provided looks like I'm SOL?

Comment: Then you need to install an older version of `mysql-connector` that is compatible with the database I think

Comment: Thanks joris; sent these links to the admin and looks like they have a mirror of the DB exactly for things like this. It's working now :-)